# "Digg bar" style bar for stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, diggbar

Not sure what others think of the digg bar (also appears on stumbleupon.com, popurls.com) but I think it could be a nice inclusion for browsing tags in stackoverflow by reducing the need for back/forward the whole time. Plus the random button would be a good way of finding new questions.

The bar would need to do unanswered questions I imagine.

Comment: Make us one with greasemonkey :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please no iframes, whatever you do!  I don't want to follow some external links and still be stuck in a SO iframe.

Answer (score 3):

I hate the Digg bar and it's one major reason why I never bother visiting that site anymore. For the most part I think the UI of StackOverflow is spot-on and adding extras like that on top of it will end up cluttering it more than anything else, IMHO.

If it is something that is off by default which can then be turned on by individual users, then maybe I won't have an issue with it.